# Rotate sprite according to onMouseMove cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBcm0.png)

```
auto spr= Sprite::create("spr.png");
spr->setPosition(Vec2(500, 500);
spr->setScale(0.2);
layer->addChild(gun, 1);
```

What do I need to do so my sprite can rotate my head according to the mouse position

```
void HelloWorld::onMouseMove(Event *event)
{   
   EventMouse* e = (EventMouse*)event;
   (................)
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBcm0.png):

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
const float PI = 3.1415;

void HelloWorld::onMouseMove(Event *event)
{    
    float dx = evnt->getCursorX() - spr->getPosition().x;
    float dy = evnt->getCursorY() - spr->getPosition().y;

    float rotation = (atan2(dx, dy)) * 180 / PI;

    spr->setRotation(rotation);
}
```

I don't understand what you mean with "so my sprite can rotate my head" but that is the way to rotate a sprite, so apply it to whatever sprite you need.

Hope it helps! :D